# Plotting a very large number of points on HTML5 canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory, d3.js

I am trying to draw a huge (60k) number of (x, y) points on an HTML5 canvas and simulate streaming data points with D3.js in Chrome and Firefox, and finding that the browser freezes and crashes after about 10 seconds.

I am generating the data set with random values as follows:

```
var data = d3.range(60000).map(function() { return Math.random() * 500; });
```

Would it help to break generation of data into sections? I feel that this might be caused by trying to store such a large data set at one time as I have shown.

Is there any way that I can prevent this from happening? Such as drawing and saving smaller sections as tiled images?

Added code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    w = 100 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
      .node();

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    . range([0,w])
    .domain([0,h]);


    data = d3.range(60000).map(function(){return Math.random()*500});
    data.forEach(function(d,i) {
      context.strokeStyle="red";
      context.lineWidth="1";
      context.lineTo(scale(++k),scale(d));
      context.stroke();
    });
```

Comment: I have no idea what sort of chart or drawing you are trying to achieve, but have you considered using WebGL in order to leverage the GPU?

Comment: The question is little wrong here are you making this on canvas or svg using d3.

Comment: I am using the canvas.

Comment: I even have this failing:     for (j = 0; j < 1400; j++){ 
       data = d3.range(40).map(function(){return Math.random()*400});

Comment: My concern is that having 60K (x,y) coordinates stream in will just cause the same crashing.

Comment: data = d3.range(60000).map(function(){return Math.random()*500});
this hardly takes milliseconds
hmm...if you are using canvas then it will freeze for the time it draws 60k points... not always as you claiming. the reason is something else...can you make a fiddle. once the canvas is drawn it should not freeze at all...

Comment: Here is a fiddle, it wont even load for me http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1494/

Comment: Also the reason I had stroke in the loop, I was hoping have it draw out the path overtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking a completely different question in the comment section I thought of put it another answer.

Comments and working code inline.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    w = 100 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
      .node();

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var data = d3.range(11).map(function(){return Math.random()*10})
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 700]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([10, 290]);
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d,i) {console.log(x(i));return x(i);})
      .y(function(d) {return y(d);})
    //making a dummy SVG
    var path = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("fill", "none").remove();
   d3.select("body svg").remove();

    //going from 0 to the paths total length and storing all the points
    var points = [];
    for(var i =0; i < path.node().getTotalLength(); i++){
        points.push(path.node().getPointAtLength(i));//store point @ that length
    }
    var id = window.setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Doing")
      var point = points.shift();//take each point
      context.strokeStyle="red";
      context.lineWidth="1";
      context.lineTo(point.x,point.y);
      context.stroke();
      if(points.length <= 0){
        console.log("Finished")
        window.clearInterval(id);//clear the interval since the drawing is complete
      }
    }, 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.10/d3.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Working code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yyX4uCL0HTEEwWMsv7OQ).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
data.forEach(function(d,i) {
      context.strokeStyle="red";
      context.lineWidth="1";
      context.lineTo(scale(++k),scale(d));
      context.stroke();//this should be out of the for loop you should be doing it once not everytime
    });
```

Something like this:

```
data.forEach(function(d,i) {
  context.strokeStyle="red";
  context.lineWidth="1";
  var j = scale(d);
  var m = scale(d++);
  context.lineTo(j,m);
});
context.stroke();
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh3OodqJN2blhW6J9GDI?p=info)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cyril is there anyway that is could be animated as a path, On the canvas rather than in SVG so that it appears similar to http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326 ?

Comment: Bob, If I have answered your concern in the answer above please
mark it as accepted. For your second query please make another SO question and i can copy my other answer there. So that it be helpful for others who have similar issue.